# PHP user account type highlighting in CSS

Tags: php, css

I have some problem getting the user account type from db.
I create a column on db called acc_type, it checks if user acc_type is 1 or greater highlight the user name.

I wrote this code but it highlights all the username as red admin.

```
colors meaning:
Blue = Regular member = 0
Red = admin = 1
Green = Mod = 2
Orange = Super User = 3
```

Code here

```
<?php
if($dn5['acc_type'] =='0')
{
echo '<style>
.acc{
color:blue;
}
</style>';
}else if($dn5['acc_type']=='1'){
echo '<style>
.acc{
color:red;
}
</style>';
}else if($dn5['acc_type']=='2'){
echo '<style>
.acc{
color:green;
}
</style>';
}
?>
<span class="acc"><?php echo $username;?></span>
```

Comment: Sounds like `$dn5['acc_type']` equals '1' then. Try using `echo $dn5['acc_type']` to see what is printed and verify it is not in fact '1'

Comment: getting numbers from acc_type. like: if its admin then acc_type is 1, for mod is 2

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked what values you're passing into $dn5['acc_type']?

As well, your code is rather repetitive, you could simplify it greatly with something like

```
switch($dn5['acc_type']) {
    case 1:   $color = 'red';    break;
    case 2:   $color = 'green';  break;
    default:  $color = 'blue'; 
}
echo "<style>.acc { color: $color; }</style>";
```

Comment: i am using : 
    '$req = mysql_query('select acc_type from users Where      id="'.$id.'"');
$dn5 = mysql_fetch_array($req)' . 
$acc_type data type is Int

the code didn't work

Comment: i used the same code for users profile page and it worked fine.
Code: http://pastebin.com/Wsdn3E18

Comment: This isn't a PHP problem, it's a CSS one. He's outputting multiple <style> blocks, but using the same classname.

Comment: OMG - your right its the css problem, i removed the css code and replace the img and it worked perfectly. Thanks man, and thanks to the other members.

Comment: @madara: but the blocks are output conditionally, based on that var value. if it was multiple blocks, then the LAST duplicated class would take effect, which make everything green instead.

Comment: ok how to get 2 row in 1 if statement:
if(isset($dnn['acc_type'] == 1) && isset($dnn['acc_type'] == 2))
{

Comment: you might want to read up on boolean logic. think of exactly how a single variable could possibly have TWO different values at the same time...